# Flutter Provider integer Reset

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have a count variable like this:

```dart
class Count with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 1;

  int get count => _count;

  void setCount(bool isIncrement) {
    if (isIncrement) {
      _count = checkCount(_count + 1);
    } else {
      _count = checkCount(_count - 1);
      print("decrement" + _count.toString());
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  int checkCount(int count) {
    if (count < 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (count > 10) {
      return 10;
    } else {
      return count;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the provider to use it on the food pages. But when I switch between the pages, the count variable continues from where it left off. I want it to restart as 1 every time the page changes.

```dart
class Hamburger extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hamburger({super.key, required Count count});

  @override
  State<Hamburger> createState() => _HamburgerState();
}

class _HamburgerState extends State<Hamburger> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color coloricon = Provider.of<iconcolor>(context).coloricon;
    int count = Provider.of<Count>(context).count;
    return Scaffold(
      …
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Create Provider in every page not before material app.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Provider is to have a consistent state across all your pages.

If you want to save only the number of hamburgers selected you need a variable similar to `_hamburgerCount` and control it there.

Or, for a more scalable solution, you can create a `Map<String, int>` or something similar to store the amount of each type. There is many ways to solve this, but with one global count variable you can not achieve storing a count for each type of food.